# jQuery Mobile Collapsible Sets leave empty space

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm currently using jQuery Mobile 1.3.0. In this I'm using Collapsible sets and every time I expand one and then either expand a different one or collapse the original one it leaves an empty space at the bottom of the page. Does anybody know of or have a fix for this?

Comment: Show us an example. Create a jsFiddle example or post your page HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with Collapsible set that on the collapse sometimes was leaving blank white space on the bottom of the page. I solved this by adding attribute android:overScrollMode="never" to the WebView. Please try this - it might help.